# how to stop spiders/crawlers on tcl webserver

Tags: web-crawler, webserver, tcl

I have an application that will be hosted on a tclhttpd server. I wanted to know if there's a way I can block web crawlers to read the directory structure.
PS: I read about robots.txt . But the problem that I found with that was there is no way of stopping a bot from reading more even if I provide robots.txt file.
Any help is greatly appretiated.
TIA

Comment: This is not a programming question.   You would be better off asking on superuser.   Use a firewall, Use a blacklist.   Use authentication.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, but the easiest is probably to put the Tcl webserver behind an nginx instance. (Apache would work well too, but I don't like configuring apache; it doesn't work the way I think.) You can then use all the usual recipes for dealing with spiders and crawlers that are documented for that system. You can also use load balancing configurations to put multiple servers behind a single port. There are lots of options, depending on how much work you want to do and what your budget is.

However, none of these are really programming solutions so much as *deployment* solutions. As such, they are better answered on other Stack Exchange sites (e.g., Server Fault). The good part is that Tcl programs tend to run fairly lightweight, so putting multiple instances on a single server is quite practical.